# Rounding by HttpServletResponse setDateHeader

Tags: java, servlets

The method [`HttpServletResponse.setDateHeader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setDateHeader%28java.lang.String,%20long%29) adds an HTTP date header for a given time-stamp. The given value is in  milliseconds since the epoch. But [HTTP dates](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1) have second precision, so the implementation must round the given value. But how does it round it (up, down, nearest?), and where is it specified how it *should* round it? Or should you always given it rounded values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet 3.0 Specification doesn't say a word about this. I took a look to Tomcat 7 source code and it just ignore the milliseconds. It uses the folowing date format to render the date:

```
public static final String 
        HTTP_RESPONSE_DATE_HEADER = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
```